# Creating a Polygon, with a hole, in Shapely

Tags: python, polygon, geometry, shapely, multi-polygon

So I have two polygons: (i) An outer polygon, and (ii) an inner Polygon representing the 'hole'. I'm trying to merge these two to give a single Polygon, with the hole.

For easy illustration, the outer Polygon looks like:

[image]

And the (ii) Hole looks like:

[image]

Both these Polygons are Shapely Polygons. To create a Polygon with the hole, I researched a lot through this exchange and although I found limited resources, I tried the following:

```
#x: Shapely Polygon Type - The outer Polygon
#y: Shapely Polygon Type - The 'hole'
w=geometry.Polygon(x, holes=[y])
```

I still seem to be getting the same issue, the hole is not represented. Any tips?

Comment: If they're already `Polygon` objects then try `w = x.difference(y)`

Comment: @mikewatt thank you so much! This is exactly what I was looking for. If you can make it into a formal answer, I'll gladly accept it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If starting with two `Polygon` objects then you can use the [`object.difference()` method](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/stable/manual.html#object.difference):

```
with_hole = outer.difference(inner)
```